# Only run Facebook log-in when user clicks button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook SDK to retrieve the current logged in user on Facebook and output their name and e-mail address.

The issue I am having is when a user visits my page their name and e-mail address is automatically being displayed. I would like this to only happen if they click the Facebook log-in function.

My JS is:

```
function statusChangeCallback(response)
{
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      updateUIWithFacebookFields();
    }
}

function checkLoginState()
{
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'snipped',
        cookie     : false,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.1'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
    {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
};

(function(d, s, id)
{
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function updateUIWithFacebookFields()
{
    FB.api('/me', function(response)
    {

        var registerUsernameElm = document.getElementById('username');
        var registerUserEmailElm = document.getElementById('useremail');

        if(registerUsernameElm)
        {
            registerUsernameElm.value = response.name;
        }
        if(registerUserEmailElm)
        {
            registerUserEmailElm.value = response.email;
        }

    });
}
```

And my button code is:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" size="large" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button></span>
```

How can I only have this run when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I'm surprised nobody wanted to answer this.  I had this same problem just a few minutes ago and searched for the same question.  Since I find no answer to our exactly the same question, I tried to experiment on my own.  So here is what I came up with but using your own example:

On this part of your code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
FB.init({
    appId      : 'snipped',
    cookie     : false,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.1'
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
{
    statusChangeCallback(response);
});
};
```

I just removed the part FB.getLoginStatus since this will be called when you press the button.  So your code becomes:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
FB.init({
    appId      : 'snipped',
    cookie     : false,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.1'
});
};
```

That's it!

It was a simple solution that I can think of so I'm not sure if it is the best practice.  Since this question is 2 months old, you probably found your own solution by now, kindly to share what you did so I can be assured if what I did is correct.  Thanks!